# ReactJS Server side rendering used as template engine

Tags: reactjs, react-server

I want to know if anyone came across `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup` that outputs pure `HTML`?

Currently the function `renderToStaticMarkup` is merging together React elements which kinda makes my application slow.

Comment: I'm honestly not surprised that it is actually, in general, very slow to render an entire React VDOM tree. Maybe look at [react-ssr-optimization](https://github.com/walmartlabs/react-ssr-optimization).

Comment: thank you for your comment, I really don't need the optimization, because for this specific task, i'm not using it properly, i am just using it as template engine, performance isn't dramatically bad, but makes pretty visible difference compared to rendering pure string and only for the reason that the library i'm using is re-rendering it self, everytime a change occurred, that means rendering new instance of react component

Comment: Then perhaps I would recommend that you cache the result.